# System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to decrypt an encrypted file, however I am getting the `System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.` error in line 4 of the above method (StreamReader...). Can anyone tell me why this exact error is happening? I dont have any path being passed the method where error is occuring however the path from the previous method is an absolute path of the file to decrypt

Method:

```
   public static string AsymmDecrypt(string input, string privatekeyfilename)
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider myAlg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(privatekeyfilename);
            myAlg.FromXmlString(sr.ReadLine());
            sr.Close();

            byte[] cipher = myAlg.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(input), true);
            return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipher);
        }
```

Parameters being passed:

```
input = "����\0JFIF\0\0H\0H\0\0��\0C\0\b"

privatekeyfilename = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>2o6sUW4eEF43RK6SWyxuII0wfmhyiTXkBVX8l5J20Y5IvY10/7W3vT0RkwB/lcZUNUgOC2PG6ISJQ53PR76yybSodU9uNmYZye+eJnImP+a6SFZKMxeFESFkye5kroHc4qQ76Zyb37YcMulD214EWnyiu3gcBoA5yyOXyM8PojU=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>7Ke13x362OFEr7VjYmpJOpC+...
```

Stack Trace:

```
    [ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.]
   System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional) +10631190
   System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path) +21
   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost) +82
   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path) +32
   eLearningLTD.Securities.EncryptDecrypt.AsymmDecrypt(String input, String privatekeyfilename) in D:\Assignments\SSD\aAssignment\eLearningLTD\eLearningLTD\Securities\EncryptDecrypt.cs:211
   eLearningLTD.Securities.EncryptDecrypt.HybridDecryption(String filePath, String publicKey, String privateKey) in D:\Assignments\SSD\aAssignment\eLearningLTD\eLearningLTD\Securities\EncryptDecrypt.cs:178
   eLearningLTD.Controllers.ResourcesController.download(String id) in D:\Assignments\SSD\aAssignment\eLearningLTD\eLearningLTD\Controllers\ResourcesController.cs:213
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +214
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +253
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +324
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +106
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +48
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:
`StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(privatekeyfilename);`
It expects a [path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but instead you just pass your privatekey.

To fix the problem you have to replace:

```
     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(privatekeyfilename);
     myAlg.FromXmlString(sr.ReadLine());
     sr.Close();
```

With

```
     myAlg.FromXmlString(privatekeyfilename);
```